# z-index issue on Essential Grid / fancybox plugin - WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, lightbox, marketo

I've recreated the issue in my development server using the same settings when creating a lightbox in the Essential Grid plugin for WordPress.

Here is the url: http://dev-site.ofsgraphics.com/grid-settings/ I created 8 skins - the Marketo skin has an orange button and white bg (2nd row)

You will notice that it take several clicks on the Marketo Button for the lightbox to show up. Can we troubleshoot this issue?

Upon the lightbox load, I cannot fill out the form fields - I tried rearranging the z-index of different containers involved but does not seem to work.

Can we also make sure on click Submit, that there is no issue?

The form page is created using Marketo.

Comment: I haven't seen your site but make sure you have `position:relative` set for elements with `z-index`. Z-index only works when you specify `position`.

Answer (score 0):

Marketo button is firing an Ajax call so it is waiting for the response and hence the lag.

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to fire the loadForm method on a hidden form element first, and then change it to display on the button click to avoid the latency during user input.

Comment: thanks. correct me if i'm wrong. basically the button on the skin calls the lightbox feature to load the page which also calls the marketo form / script.

Comment: @kelkington would you be able to explain if my answer is right? could you provide me some dorection?

Comment: this is just for loading the form. another issue is i cannot fill out the form.

Comment: @kelkington hi. do u have a reference i can test? thanks.

Comment: can this be achieved by jquery? load marketo form on hidden element then show onclick of the button.